# innerHTML injects unwanted characters between items

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to inject array of items to html with innerHTML.

```
let itemsToInject = [`<li><img src='icon1.png' alt=''></li>`,`<li><img src='icon2.png' alt=''></li>`];
content.innerHTML = itemsToInject.map(item => item);
```

- note that **itemsToInject** array contains 40 items in original, that's why I'm using map to change innerHTML.

It works perfectly and injects items. However, there is a problem in DOM. It automatically inserts unwanted characters (",") between list items.

Looks like that:

```
<li>...</li>
","
<li>...</li>
```

I've tried to remove them by regex, but it failed.

- **What causes that situation?**
- **How to avoid that?**

Comment: itemsToInject.map(item => item).join('')

Comment: @syduki it worked thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```js
content = document.body
let itemsToInject = [`<li>IMG 1<img src='icon1.png' alt=''></li>`, `<li>IMG 2<img src='icon2.png' alt=''></li>`];
itemsToInject.forEach(item => content.innerHTML += item);
```

Or this:

```js
content = document.body
let itemsToInject = [`<li>IMG 1<img src='icon1.png' alt=''></li>`, `<li>IMG 2<img src='icon2.png' alt=''></li>`];
content.innerHTML = itemsToInject.join('')
```

The situation is being caused because you are setting the innerHTML to a javascript list, so the browser is forced to convert it to a string - and that's exactly what it does.

To avoid it, simply don't pass an array or list into innerHTML!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.join("")` to join all element of the array together:

```js
elements = ["<p>hello</p>", "<p>bye</p>"]

document.querySelector("#without").innerHTML = elements
document.querySelector("#with").innerHTML    = elements.join("")
```

```html
<div id="without"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="with"></div>
```